# Using recursion in pygame

Tags: python

I'm new to python and programming in general and am working on a final project for a python centric class. One of the requirements that I cant seem to figure out how to make work is to integrate recursion into our code in order to show a working knowledge. I've worked up a simple "bullet hell" style game using pygame.

My goal is that when contact is made between a bullet and an enemy, that a series of bullet sets will be launched from the player position as a sort of short-term modifier.

This code runs in the main loop whenever a bullet hits an enemy:

```
     for i in reversed(range(len(bullets))):
            for j in reversed(range(len(enemies))):
                if bullets[i].collided(enemies[j].rect):
                    del enemies[j]
                    del bullets[I]

                    s.global_score += 100
                    more_bullets(10)

                    #print("Hit!")
                    #print(s.global_score)
                    break
```

The "more_bullets" function is the focus of my recursion, and calls this:

```
def more_bullets(n):
    if(n > 0):

        spawnx = sq.rect.x+10 + sq.rect.width/2 - 10
        b = Square(s.red, spawnx,sq.rect.y, 10,30)
        b.direction = 'N'
        b.player_speed = 10
        bullets.append(b)

        spawnx = sq.rect.x-10 + sq.rect.width/2 - 10
        b = Square(s.red, spawnx,sq.rect.y, 10,30)
        b.direction = 'N'
        b.player_speed = 10
        bullets.append(b)

        pygame.display.update()

        more_bullets(n-1)

        print(f"Fired x {n}")
```

The outcome currently is that my debug does print 10 times making me think that the recursion is functioning correctly, however only one set of bullets is firing when the collision occurs. I'm thinking that all 10 bullets are firing faster than I can register it and just stacking on the screen.

Is there an easy-to-use function that might slow down the firing of the bullets? or have messed up something more fundamentally here?

Comment: Can you force an animation tick after you fire each bullet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm thinking that all 10 bullets are firing faster than I can register it and just stacking on the screen.

You're correct.

I don't believe there's an "easy way" to do what you're asking the way you think. The recursion is immediate, meaning that the function runs 10 times right away when it's called. For it to send out a burst of staggered bullets, you'd need some kind of timer or queue or something along those lines that runs alongside your main loop, and recursion isn't really a natural fit for that. The same will go for any kind of game logic function that plays out over a period of time.

This isn't what's being asked, but here's an idea of what you could do, even though it's kind of a redundant use of recursion: add a parameter to that function that dictates the angle the bullet is being shot. Then, add a little bit to that parameter on every recursive call. That way an arc of bullets will be shot at the same time.

Comment: Awesome. So I didn't quite use your suggestion, but you definitely prompted the context I needed to figure out a work-around. By using n as a variable to modify the spawn location off the bullets, I've created a line of bullets creating a similar effect, and showing the use of recursion, thanks a bunch for the comment